# Deathtrap confusing ally/enemy

Tags: borderlands-2

I really like to play as Gaige, but sometimes, deathtrap seems to be confused, who he is using his skills on.
I see him boosting the shields of enemies or attacking me and my friends with the red laser or the blue shock thing.
Is this intended (as deathtrap is not a commercial robot, but rather a "hobby-project" and thus incomplete) or a glitch?

Its just really annoying, when you are in fight for your life mode, and you have a quite low enemy in front of you, ready to die, but dt comes in and boosts his shields, so you die...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a glitch, but it was fixed [on patch v1.3.1 (9th January '13)](https://gearboxsoftware.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205280050--PC-Update-Hot-Fix-Information) :

> "Deathtrap can no longer restore an enemy's shields, even though it was hilarious."

You are probably confusing the shield healing with his electrical beam attack which look the same.